# Can I continue using the app after it is disconnected from computer?

Tags: ios, flutter

When I disconnect my iPhone from my computer, the app crashes, and when I re-launch it I get a white screen saying "debug mode flutter apps can only be launched from Flutter tooling..." Is there a way that I can continue using the app after it is disconnected like I can do with Xcode apps?

Answer (score 1):

solved by running flutter run --release in terminal

Answer (score 0):

In Android, I had this problem, but by getting the apk, this problem was solved easily